# dpkg error when install qt4: can not overwrite /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I have install qt4 and qt5, but qt4 is incomplete.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:

> libqt4-network : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7.1+dfsg-1+dde) but it is not installed
> libqt4-opengl : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7.1+dfsg-1+dde) but it is not installed
> .......

When I try to install dependencies like libqtcore4, I meet the dpkg error:

> **dpkg:** error processing archive >/var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7.1+dfsg-1+dde_amd64.deb(--unpack):

> trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf', which is also in package libqt5core5a:amd64 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1

The following is the qt information in my machine (Deepin OS,i3wm):

> ~$ qtchooser -l

> 4
> 5
> default
> qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
> qt4
> qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
> qt5

> ~$ cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf

> /usr/lib/qt5/bin
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *Deepin is neither Ubuntu, nor flavor of Ubuntu*

Comment: Qt4 is EOL and was removed from Ubuntu in 2019 (2015 upstream was announced EOL though Debian & Ubuntu supported it until 15-Mar-2019) ; (for more details refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295). The package if maintained should have been ported to Qt5 (introduced 19-Dec-2012) before now